# Graphical Representation of Lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Say I have three lists: `a={1,5,10,15}  b={2,4,6,8}` and `c={1,1,0,1,0}`. I want a plot which has `a` as the `x` axis, `b` as the `y` axis and a red/black dot to mark 1/0. For. e.g. The coordinate `(5,4)` will have a red dot.
In other words the coordinate `(a[i],b[i])` will have a red/black dot depending on whether `c[i]` is 1 or 0.
I have been trying my hand with `ListPlot` but can't figure out the options.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is a general problem in mma. Often I have a set of data points that I'd like to plot differently depending on some 3rd, or 4th, bit of data. `ErrorListPlot` does this, but it is too specialized and it would be nice to specify functions that supply graphics primitives based upon the auxillary data. I know that Mark Caprio is working on something like that for the LevelScheme packages, so I'll have to show him this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest this.

```
a = {1, 5, 10, 15};
b = {2, 4, 6, 8};
c = {1, 1, 0, 1};

Graphics[
  {#, Point@{##2}} & @@@ 
    Thread@{c /. {1 -> Red, 0 -> Black}, a, b},
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or shorter but more obfuscated

```
Graphics[
  {Hue[1, 1, #], Point@{##2}} & @@@ Thread@{c, a, b}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> 0
]
```

Comment: +1, I like this one the best as it melds the three lists together with a clever use of Apply (`@@@`), SlotSequence (`##2`), Thread, and ReplaceAll (`/.`). (The use of SlotSequence alone would have merited the +1.) The other answers require additional work to set and combine the color list with the coords from a and b.

Comment: Thank you.  I hope that skr finds it intelligible.

Comment: Very elegant! I like how Thread did the work of two Transpose[] (in my code below).  Also, the SlotSequence was something I wouldn't have thought of (before seeing your example).

Comment: +1 Very cool solution - nothing extraneous, everything is here because it has to be.

Comment: Which do you all find cleaner, `& @@@ Thread@{c, a, b}` or `& ~MapThread~ {c, a, b}` ?

Comment: @skr if you like my answer, will you accept it? (the checkmark)  It would be my first accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Leonid's idea, perhaps more naive.

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := 
 ListPlot[Pick[Transpose[{a, b}], c, #] & /@ {0, 1}, 
       PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], {Blue, Red}}]

f[a, b, c]
```

[image]

**Edit: Just for fun**

```
f[h_, a_, b_, c_, opt___] := 
 h[Pick[Transpose[{a, b}], c, #] & /@ {0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], {Blue, Red}}, opt]  

f[ ListPlot, 
   Sort@RandomReal[1, 100], 
   Sin[(2 \[Pi] #)/100] + RandomReal[#/100] & /@ Range[100], 
   RandomInteger[1, 100], 
      Joined -> True, 
      InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
      Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: I like that. :-)   What is the purpose of Directive?

Comment: @Mr. What Directive? er... :D

Answer (score 6):

Here are your points:

```
a = {1, 5, 10, 15};
b = {2, 4, 6, 8};
c = {1, 1, 0, 1};
```

(I deleted the last element from `c` to make it the same length as `a` and `b`). What I'd suggest is to separately make images for points with zeros and ones and then combine them  - this seems easiest in this situation:

```
showPoints[a_, b_, c_] :=
With[{coords = Transpose[{a, b}]},
   With[{plotF = ListPlot[Pick[coords, c, #], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> #2] &},
     Show[MapThread[plotF, {{0, 1}, {Black, Red}}]]]]
```

Here is the usage:

```
showPoints[a, b, c]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Ha! I looked late at your answer ... after doing the same. Almost post it to my shame :)

Comment: @belisarius  There were a couple of times when I was in the same situation w.r.t. your answers, so we are even now :). But, seriously, for this one, I liked some other answers more than mine.

Comment: @Leonid Perhaps other answers are more concise and clean, but I thought ListPlot as the "natural" way to go, just because you could use ListLinePlot with all its options after that.

Comment: @belisarius  My (perhaps unconscious) motivation for choosing this construct was that it is high-level, that is, completely independent of the internal representation of points. Should that change at some point (pun unintended), the construct we used is the one most likely to survive. But, it won't win the succinctness contest. Perhaps, your motivation was similar?

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin I do appreciate the logic of your strategy.  I try to use high-level functions for most things, but since the graphics system changes in version 6, I find myself using graphics primitives more and more.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't use the graphics primitives all that often, but I agree the changes in v.6 did make it much easier to use and create simple things this way. Like the others I prefer the higher lvl constructs, but they're not as straightforward in this case.

Comment: @Leonid couldn't resist and posted my code. Almost the same as yours, just to show the ListPlot way can be written more concise. Nothing new there, though.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility:

```
ListPlot[List /@ Transpose[{a, b}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {1, 1, 0, 1} /. {1 -> { Style[\[FilledCircle], Red], 10}, 
   0 -> { { Style[\[FilledCircle], Black], 10}}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Giving as output:

[image]

Comment: +1, for convincing ListPlot to do you your work using PlotMarkers.

Answer (score 4):

You could obtain similar results (to those of Leonid) using Graphics:

```
    Graphics[{PointSize[.02], Transpose[{(c/. {1 -> Red, 0 -> Black}), 
              Point /@ Transpose[{a, b}]}]},
              Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Using Graphics instead of ListPlot]